# I want to fire & forget an HTTP calls which returns an Observable. I found that it is blocking the main thread

Tags: rx-java

```
client.cacheLoad(((CxyAccount) account).getAccountNumber(), Cxy.getTasTrackingNumber(messageContext))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe();

client.cacheLoad(((CxyAccount) account).getAccountNumber(), Cxy.getTasTrackingNumber(messageContext))
// **Returns an Observable.**
```

Comment: We have nowhere near enough information to help you. I suspect that the `cacheLoad()` method is doing the actual blocking. You may need to wrap it in `Observable.fromCallable()`

Comment: I want execute client.cacheLoad() as fire & forget which returns an Observable from a SpringBoot app. When use subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) it is blocking the main thread. How I can achieve the executing the method without caring about the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If `client.cacheLoad()` is blocking the main thread, you can use the following:

```
Observable.fromCallable( () -> client.cacheLoad(((CxyAccount) account).getAccountNumber(), Cxy.getTasTrackingNumber(messageContext)) )
  .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
  .subscribe();
```

This will run the `client.cacheLoad()` operation on one of the threads provided by the `Schedulers.io()` schedulers.